# Remove characters from string if they exist PHP

Tags: php

I'm working with the mailgun API and webhooks.  Sometimes the message-id will include < and > but other times it wont.

**In my controller, I am trying to check if the message-id contains < and > and if so then remove it and store that in a variable.**

I may need to use `rtrim` or `str_replace` but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this? Maybe regex?

Here is an example of one mailgun returns when the event is delivered:

```
<20180203002650.1.EEE3119CC37C5A82@domain.com>
```

Here is one when mailgun returns when the event is opened. (notice it is the same message ID now it does not contain < and >

```
20180203002650.1.EEE3119CC37C5A82@domain.com
```

Links:
[Mailgun API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#event-types), 
[rtrim](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_rtrim.asp), 
[str_replace](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)

Comment: i would use trim() bob would use str_replace, sam would use a regular expresion, you can use what ever you want

Comment: Just in case you are looking for a regex way, `preg_match("/^<.+>$/", $str)` can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [trim function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) (to be exact, its overload that takes two arguments) can do the job pretty quickly and pretty well. In my opinion, using a regular expression in this case is an overkill.

```
<?php

    $str = '<20180203002650.1.EEE3119CC37C5A82@domain.com>';
    $str_trimmed = trim($str, '<>');
    echo $str_trimmed; // 20180203002650.1.EEE3119CC37C5A82@domain.com

?>
```

You can see a working demo [here](https://eval.in/948429).

Answer (score 1):

this function should do what you need.

```
$str = '<20180203002650.1.EEE3119CC37C5A82@domain.com>';

$cleanString = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<|>|and/',
    function ($matches) {
        return "";
    },
    $str
);

echo $cleanString;
```